# How to get child element by ID in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have following html:

```
<div id="note">
<textarea id="textid" class="textclass">Text</textarea>
</div>
```

How can I get textarea element? I can't use `document.getElementById("textid")` for it

I'm doing it like this now:

```
var note = document.getElementById("note");
var notetext = note.querySelector('#textid');
```

but it doesn't work in IE(8)

How else I can do it? jQuery is ok

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `document.getElementById("textid")`? If you can do `querySelector('#textid')` then the other one should be possible as well. If you have multiple elements with the same ID.... well, you have to change that.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get this element to change it's ID, I also need to do some other actions on it, that's why I want it in var.

Comment: That does not really answer my question.

Comment: Changing the id of an element is usually an awful idea. State is better handled with class or data.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If jQuery is okay, you can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/). It's basically equivalent to the way you are doing it right now.

```
$('#note').find('#textid');
```

You can also use jQuery selectors to basically achieve the same thing:

```
$('#note #textid');
```

Using these methods to get something that already has an ID is kind of strange, but I'm supplying these assuming it's not really how you plan on using it.

On a side note, you should know ID's should be unique in your webpage. If you plan on having multiple elements with the same "ID" consider using a specific class name.

**Update 2020.03.10**

It's a breeze to use native JS for this:

```
document.querySelector('#note #textid');
```

If you want to first find `#note` then `#textid` you have to check the first querySelector result. If it fails to match, chaining is no longer possible :(

```
var parent = document.querySelector('#note');
var child = parent ? parent.querySelector('#textid') : null;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a pure JavaScript solution (without jQuery)

```
var _Utils = function ()
{
    this.findChildById = function (element, childID, isSearchInnerDescendant) // isSearchInnerDescendant <= true for search in inner childern 
    {
        var retElement = null;
        var lstChildren = isSearchInnerDescendant ? Utils.getAllDescendant(element) : element.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < lstChildren.length; i++)
        {
            if (lstChildren[i].id == childID)
            {
                retElement = lstChildren[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        return retElement;
    }

    this.getAllDescendant = function (element, lstChildrenNodes)
    {
        lstChildrenNodes = lstChildrenNodes ? lstChildrenNodes : [];

        var lstChildren = element.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < lstChildren.length; i++) 
        {
            if (lstChildren[i].nodeType == 1) // 1 is 'ELEMENT_NODE'
            {
                lstChildrenNodes.push(lstChildren[i]);
                lstChildrenNodes = Utils.getAllDescendant(lstChildren[i], lstChildrenNodes);
            }
        }

        return lstChildrenNodes;
    }        
}
var Utils = new _Utils;
```

Example of use:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.innerHTML = "<table id='tableToolbar'>" +
                        "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" +
                                "<div id='divIdToSearch'>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</td>" +
                        "</tr>" +
                    "</table>";

var divToSearch = Utils.findChildById(myDiv, "divIdToSearch", true);
```

Comment: Not a good idea to change object prototype and not sure why one would get by I'd in such a way as its probably slower then document.getElementById https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FInheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes

Comment: document.getElementById is the solution, of curse!. However if your element had NOT been yet attached to the document, this method wan't work. And to use element.getElementById isn't defined on all elements. If you can get the excepted result with getElementById, go for it, however it's not always the case. Regarding the object prototype, I accept you comment, and I edit the the answer, so the function won't be part of the object methods, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Dwell in atom)

<div id="note">

   <textarea id="textid" class="textclass">Text</textarea>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var note = document.getElementById('textid').value;

   alert(note);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
$('#note textarea');
```

or just

```
$('#textid');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(selectedDOM).find();
```

function looking for **all dom objects inside the selected DOM**.
i.e.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <div id="innerDiv">
         <a href="#">link</a>
         <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

here if you write;

```
$("#mainDiv").find("p");
```

you will get tree p elements together. On the other side,

```
$("#mainDiv").children("p");
```

Function searching in the just **children DOMs of the selected DOM object**. So, by this code you will get just **paragraph 1** and **paragraph 2**. It is so beneficial to prevent browser doing unnecessary progress.